# Cannot use pip install pytorch-pretrained-bert

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I was trying to use "pip install pytorch-pretrained-bert", but I met a unseen problem. It says that the version of botocore is not satisfied. They need botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.54. However, according to the rest information, I found that the latest version of botocore is 1.17.53, it never actually reached 1.17.54. So I'm wondering how to solve this problem. Thanks for your help!

The error message is as follows,
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.54 (from boto3->pytorch-pretrained-bert) (from versions: 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.25.0, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 0.29.0, 0.30.0, 0.31.0, 0.32.0, 0.33.0, 0.34.0, 0.35.0, 0.36.0, 0.37.0, 0.38.0, 0.39.0, 0.40.0, 0.41.0, 0.42.0, 0.43.0, 0.44.0, 0.45.0, 0.46.0, 0.47.0, 0.48.0, 0.49.0, 0.50.0, 0.51.0, 0.52.0, 0.53.0, 0.54.0, 0.55.0, 0.56.0, 0.57.0, 0.58.0, 0.59.0, 0.60.0, 0.61.0, 0.62.0, 0.63.0, 0.64.0, 0.65.0, 0.66.0, 0.67.0, 0.68.0, 0.69.0, 0.70.0, 0.71.0, 0.72.0, 0.73.0, 0.74.0, 0.75.0, 0.76.0, 0.77.0, 0.78.0, 0.79.0, 0.80.0, 0.81.0, 0.82.0, 0.83.0, 0.84.0, 0.85.0, 0.86.0, 0.87.0, 0.88.0, 0.89.0, 0.90.0, 0.91.0, 0.92.0, 0.93.0, 0.94.0, 0.95.0, 0.96.0, 0.97.0, 0.98.0, 0.99.0, 0.100.0, 0.101.0, 0.102.0, 0.103.0, 0.104.0, 0.105.0, 0.106.0, 0.107.0, 0.108.0, 0.109.0, 1.0.0a1, 1.0.0a2, 1.0.0a3, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0b2, 1.0.0b3, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.12, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2.8, 1.2.9, 1.2.10, 1.2.11, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.3.15, 1.3.16, 1.3.17, 1.3.18, 1.3.19, 1.3.20, 1.3.21, 1.3.22, 1.3.23, 1.3.24, 1.3.25, 1.3.26, 1.3.27, 1.3.28, 1.3.29, 1.3.30, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.4.23, 1.4.24, 1.4.25, 1.4.26, 1.4.27, 1.4.28, 1.4.29, 1.4.30, 1.4.31, 1.4.32, 1.4.33, 1.4.34, 1.4.35, 1.4.36, 1.4.37, 1.4.38, 1.4.39, 1.4.40, 1.4.41, 1.4.42, 1.4.43, 1.4.44, 1.4.46, 1.4.47, 1.4.48, 1.4.49, 1.4.50, 1.4.51, 1.4.52, 1.4.53, 1.4.54, 1.4.55, 1.4.56, 1.4.57, 1.4.58, 1.4.59, 1.4.60, 1.4.61, 1.4.62, 1.4.63, 1.4.64, 1.4.65, 1.4.66, 1.4.67, 1.4.68, 1.4.69, 1.4.70, 1.4.71, 1.4.72, 1.4.73, 1.4.74, 1.4.75, 1.4.76, 1.4.77, 1.4.78, 1.4.79, 1.4.80, 1.4.81, 1.4.82, 1.4.83, 1.4.84, 1.4.85, 1.4.86, 1.4.87, 1.4.88, 1.4.89, 1.4.90, 1.4.91, 1.4.92, 1.4.93, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.5.13, 1.5.14, 1.5.15, 1.5.16, 1.5.17, 1.5.18, 1.5.19, 1.5.20, 1.5.21, 1.5.22, 1.5.23, 1.5.24, 1.5.25, 1.5.26, 1.5.27, 1.5.28, 1.5.29, 1.5.30, 1.5.31, 1.5.32, 1.5.33, 1.5.34, 1.5.35, 1.5.36, 1.5.37, 1.5.38, 1.5.39, 1.5.40, 1.5.41, 1.5.42, 1.5.43, 1.5.44, 1.5.45, 1.5.46, 1.5.47, 1.5.48, 1.5.49, 1.5.50, 1.5.51, 1.5.52, 1.5.53, 1.5.54, 1.5.55, 1.5.56, 1.5.57, 1.5.58, 1.5.59, 1.5.60, 1.5.61, 1.5.62, 1.5.63, 1.5.64, 1.5.65, 1.5.66, 1.5.67, 1.5.68, 1.5.69, 1.5.70, 1.5.71, 1.5.72, 1.5.73, 1.5.74, 1.5.75, 1.5.76, 1.5.77, 1.5.78, 1.5.79, 1.5.80, 1.5.81, 1.5.82, 1.5.83, 1.5.84, 1.5.85, 1.5.86, 1.5.87, 1.5.88, 1.5.89, 1.5.90, 1.5.91, 1.5.92, 1.5.93, 1.5.94, 1.5.95, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.7.12, 1.7.13, 1.7.14, 1.7.15, 1.7.16, 1.7.17, 1.7.18, 1.7.19, 1.7.20, 1.7.21, 1.7.22, 1.7.23, 1.7.24, 1.7.25, 1.7.26, 1.7.27, 1.7.28, 1.7.29, 1.7.30, 1.7.31, 1.7.32, 1.7.33, 1.7.34, 1.7.35, 1.7.36, 1.7.37, 1.7.38, 1.7.39, 1.7.40, 1.7.41, 1.7.42, 1.7.43, 1.7.44, 1.7.45, 1.7.46, 1.7.47, 1.7.48, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.8.20, 1.8.21, 1.8.22, 1.8.23, 1.8.24, 1.8.25, 1.8.26, 1.8.27, 1.8.28, 1.8.29, 1.8.30, 1.8.31, 1.8.32, 1.8.33, 1.8.34, 1.8.35, 1.8.36, 1.8.37, 1.8.38, 1.8.39, 1.8.40, 1.8.41, 1.8.42, 1.8.43, 1.8.44, 1.8.45, 1.8.46, 1.8.47, 1.8.48, 1.8.49, 1.8.50, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.9.14, 1.9.15, 1.9.16, 1.9.17, 1.9.18, 1.9.19, 1.9.20, 1.9.21, 1.9.22, 1.9.23, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.10.9, 1.10.10, 1.10.11, 1.10.12, 1.10.13, 1.10.14, 1.10.15, 1.10.16, 1.10.17, 1.10.18, 1.10.19, 1.10.20, 1.10.21, 1.10.22, 1.10.23, 1.10.24, 1.10.25, 1.10.26, 1.10.27, 1.10.28, 1.10.29, 1.10.30, 1.10.31, 1.10.32, 1.10.33, 1.10.34, 1.10.35, 1.10.36, 1.10.37, 1.10.38, 1.10.39, 1.10.40, 1.10.41, 1.10.42, 1.10.43, 1.10.44, 1.10.45, 1.10.46, 1.10.47, 1.10.48, 1.10.49, 1.10.50, 1.10.51, 1.10.52, 1.10.53, 1.10.54, 1.10.55, 1.10.56, 1.10.57, 1.10.58, 1.10.59, 1.10.60, 1.10.61, 1.10.62, 1.10.63, 1.10.64, 1.10.65, 1.10.66, 1.10.67, 1.10.68, 1.10.69, 1.10.70, 1.10.71, 1.10.72, 1.10.73, 1.10.74, 1.10.75, 1.10.76, 1.10.77, 1.10.78, 1.10.79, 1.10.80, 1.10.81, 1.10.82, 1.10.83, 1.10.84, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.12.4, 1.12.5, 1.12.6, 1.12.7, 1.12.8, 1.12.9, 1.12.10, 1.12.11, 1.12.12, 1.12.13, 1.12.14, 1.12.15, 1.12.16, 1.12.17, 1.12.18, 1.12.19, 1.12.20, 1.12.21, 1.12.22, 1.12.23, 1.12.24, 1.12.25, 1.12.26, 1.12.27, 1.12.28, 1.12.29, 1.12.30, 1.12.31, 1.12.32, 1.12.33, 1.12.34, 1.12.35, 1.12.36, 1.12.37, 1.12.38, 1.12.39, 1.12.40, 1.12.41, 1.12.42, 1.12.43, 1.12.44, 1.12.45, 1.12.46, 1.12.47, 1.12.48, 1.12.49, 1.12.50, 1.12.51, 1.12.52, 1.12.53, 1.12.54, 1.12.55, 1.12.56, 1.12.57, 1.12.58, 1.12.59, 1.12.60, 1.12.61, 1.12.62, 1.12.63, 1.12.64, 1.12.65, 1.12.66, 1.12.67, 1.12.68, 1.12.69, 1.12.70, 1.12.71, 1.12.72, 1.12.73, 1.12.74, 1.12.75, 1.12.76, 1.12.77, 1.12.78, 1.12.79, 1.12.80, 1.12.81, 1.12.82, 1.12.83, 1.12.84, 1.12.85, 1.12.86, 1.12.87, 1.12.88, 1.12.89, 1.12.90, 1.12.91, 1.12.92, 1.12.93, 1.12.94, 1.12.95, 1.12.96, 1.12.97, 1.12.98, 1.12.99, 1.12.100, 1.12.101, 1.12.102, 1.12.103, 1.12.104, 1.12.105, 1.12.106, 1.12.107, 1.12.108, 1.12.109, 1.12.110, 1.12.111, 1.12.112, 1.12.113, 1.12.114, 1.12.115, 1.12.116, 1.12.117, 1.12.118, 1.12.119, 1.12.120, 1.12.121, 1.12.122, 1.12.123, 1.12.124, 1.12.125, 1.12.126, 1.12.127, 1.12.128, 1.12.129, 1.12.130, 1.12.131, 1.12.132, 1.12.133, 1.12.134, 1.12.135, 1.12.136, 1.12.137, 1.12.138, 1.12.139, 1.12.140, 1.12.141, 1.12.142, 1.12.143, 1.12.144, 1.12.145, 1.12.146, 1.12.147, 1.12.148, 1.12.149, 1.12.150, 1.12.151, 1.12.152, 1.12.153, 1.12.154, 1.12.155, 1.12.156, 1.12.157, 1.12.158, 1.12.159, 1.12.160, 1.12.161, 1.12.162, 1.12.163, 1.12.164, 1.12.165, 1.12.166, 1.12.167, 1.12.168, 1.12.169, 1.12.170, 1.12.171, 1.12.172, 1.12.173, 1.12.174, 1.12.175, 1.12.176, 1.12.177, 1.12.178, 1.12.179, 1.12.180, 1.12.181, 1.12.182, 1.12.183, 1.12.184, 1.12.185, 1.12.186, 1.12.187, 1.12.188, 1.12.189, 1.12.190, 1.12.191, 1.12.192, 1.12.193, 1.12.194, 1.12.195, 1.12.196, 1.12.197, 1.12.198, 1.12.199, 1.12.200, 1.12.201, 1.12.202, 1.12.203, 1.12.204, 1.12.205, 1.12.206, 1.12.207, 1.12.208, 1.12.209, 1.12.210, 1.12.211, 1.12.212, 1.12.213, 1.12.214, 1.12.215, 1.12.216, 1.12.217, 1.12.218, 1.12.219, 1.12.220, 1.12.221, 1.12.222, 1.12.223, 1.12.224, 1.12.225, 1.12.226, 1.12.227, 1.12.228, 1.12.229, 1.12.230, 1.12.231, 1.12.232, 1.12.233, 1.12.234, 1.12.235, 1.12.236, 1.12.237, 1.12.238, 1.12.239, 1.12.240, 1.12.241, 1.12.242, 1.12.243, 1.12.244, 1.12.245, 1.12.246, 1.12.247, 1.12.248, 1.12.249, 1.12.250, 1.12.251, 1.12.252, 1.12.253, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.13.3, 1.13.4, 1.13.5, 1.13.6, 1.13.7, 1.13.8, 1.13.9, 1.13.10, 1.13.11, 1.13.12, 1.13.13, 1.13.14, 1.13.15, 1.13.16, 1.13.17, 1.13.18, 1.13.19, 1.13.20, 1.13.21, 1.13.22, 1.13.23, 1.13.24, 1.13.25, 1.13.26, 1.13.27, 1.13.28, 1.13.29, 1.13.30, 1.13.31, 1.13.32, 1.13.33, 1.13.34, 1.13.35, 1.13.36, 1.13.37, 1.13.38, 1.13.39, 1.13.40, 1.13.41, 1.13.42, 1.13.43, 1.13.44, 1.13.45, 1.13.46, 1.13.47, 1.13.48, 1.13.49, 1.13.50, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.14.7, 1.14.8, 1.14.9, 1.14.10, 1.14.11, 1.14.12, 1.14.13, 1.14.14, 1.14.15, 1.14.16, 1.14.17, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.15.5, 1.15.6, 1.15.7, 1.15.8, 1.15.9, 1.15.10, 1.15.11, 1.15.12, 1.15.13, 1.15.14, 1.15.15, 1.15.16, 1.15.17, 1.15.18, 1.15.19, 1.15.20, 1.15.21, 1.15.22, 1.15.23, 1.15.24, 1.15.25, 1.15.26, 1.15.27, 1.15.28, 1.15.29, 1.15.30, 1.15.31, 1.15.32, 1.15.33, 1.15.34, 1.15.35, 1.15.36, 1.15.37, 1.15.38, 1.15.39, 1.15.40, 1.15.41, 1.15.42, 1.15.43, 1.15.44, 1.15.45, 1.15.46, 1.15.47, 1.15.48, 1.15.49, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.16.7, 1.16.8, 1.16.9, 1.16.10, 1.16.11, 1.16.12, 1.16.13, 1.16.14, 1.16.15, 1.16.16, 1.16.17, 1.16.18, 1.16.19, 1.16.20, 1.16.21, 1.16.22, 1.16.23, 1.16.24, 1.16.25, 1.16.26, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.17.6, 1.17.7, 1.17.8, 1.17.9, 1.17.10, 1.17.11, 1.17.12, 1.17.13, 1.17.14, 1.17.15, 1.17.16, 1.17.17, 1.17.18, 1.17.19, 1.17.20, 1.17.21, 1.17.22, 1.17.23, 1.17.24, 1.17.25, 1.17.26, 1.17.27, 1.17.28, 1.17.29, 1.17.30, 1.17.31, 1.17.32, 1.17.33, 1.17.34, 1.17.35, 1.17.36, 1.17.37, 1.17.38, 1.17.39, 1.17.40, 1.17.41, 1.17.42, 1.17.43, 1.17.44, 1.17.45, 1.17.46, 1.17.47, 1.17.48, 1.17.49, 1.17.50, 1.17.51, 1.17.52, 1.17.53)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for botocore<1.18.0,>=1.17.54 (from boto3->pytorch-pretrained-bert)

Comment: It's probably you need to install botocore from source https://github.com/boto/botocore

Comment: There're up to version 1.17.56 there but no one put them to pypi yet

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason why you're not using the HuggingFace implementation for BERT?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice, really appreciate that :)  @NatthaphonHongcharoen

Comment: Because I get the preprocess code from my colleagues, and this is how they use BERT, I'll consider using hugging face implementation one day. Thanks for your advice. @Seankala

Answer (score 0):

I use "conda install -c conda-forge pytorch-pretrained-bert", instead of pip install. Pretty confused about the reason behind that, but at least it's solved.